# how to display hex value in a single block

Tags: c++, winapi, char

The following code display the hex code of testbuffer one by one when went through the loop.

```
char testBuffer[5] = {0x42, 0x54, 0x43, 0x56, 0x42};

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    char temp[255];
    sprintf(temp, _T("%X"), testBuffer[i]);
    HWND hWnd = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC_READ); 
    if(hWnd)
    {
        SetWindowText(hWnd, temp);
    }
}
```

But i want to display all the value of testbuffer using single variable not using loop. Because i have to display it using only SetWindowText once not through the loop.

I have used char to define hex value. It is to represent hex value of each character of the character array.

so how to display this character array as a single block?

Comment: Win32's CryptBinaryToString can he handy for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the definition of the string buffer and call to `SetWindowText` outside the loop

```
char testBuffer[5]={0x42,0x54,0x43,0x56,0x42};
char temp[255] = {0};  // zero initialize

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  sprintf(&temp[strlen(temp)], "%02X", testBuffer[i]);
}

HWND hWnd = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC_READ); 
if ( hWnd )
{
  SetWindowText(hWnd, temp);
}
```

Passing the expression `&temp[strlen(temp)]` as the first argument to `sprintf` will cause it to always append to existing string in the buffer, this is why zero-initialing the buffer at the beginning is important. Also, note that the use of the `_T(...)` macro with `sprintf` could result in compiler errors because that function does not like wide character strings.

---

And another solution that uses standard C++ wherever possible.

```
char testBuffer[5]={0x42,0x54,0x43,0x56,0x42};
std::ostringstream oss;

oss << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::uppercase;

for(int i : testBuffer) 
{
  oss << std::setw(2) << i;
}

HWND hWnd = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC_READ); 
if ( hWnd )
{
  SetWindowText(hWnd, oss.str().c_str());
}
```

You'll need to include the headers `ios`, `iomanip` and `sstream` for this version.

Comment: Using `strlen(temp)` in the loop will gradually slow down the loop as it iterates (not so bad in this example, but may be an issue for larger buffers). You should use a separate variable that is initialized to 0 and incremented after each `sprint()`, and then use the final value to zero-terminate the buffer (avoiding having to zero-initialize the buffer beforehand): `int idx = 0; for (...) { idx += sprintf(&temp[idx], "%02X", testBuffer[i]); } temp[idx] := 0;` Or, you can use the loop counter as the index: `int i = 0; for (...; ++i) { sprintf(&temp[i*2], "%02X", testBuffer[i]); } tmp[i] = 0;`

Comment: I like the C++ approach, although `for(int i : testBuffer)` syntax is not available in all C++ compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Try forming each hex value into one string, the concat them into another:

```
char tempword[16] ;
char temp[255] ;

* tempword= '\0' ;
for (int i= 0; ( i < 5 ) ; i ++ )
{
  sprintf(tempword, "%X", testBuffer[i] ) ;
  strcat( temp, tempword ) ;
}
...
SetWindowText( hWnd, temp ) ;
```